# How can I strengthen my legs for running?

Tags: running, cardio, long-distance-running, legs

I have been running for about a year now, and am at a point now where I am able to run for 15 km. But now I have a problem. At the point where I reach 15 km, my heart and lungs are fine, I'm not even out of breath, but my legs aren't strong enough to go further. Either my calves start to ache, or my knees start to pain, or sometimes my upper legs start to become weak.

Question: How can I strengthen my legs so that I can run further, and also faster?

**EDIT**

This question is about training for > 15 km running, and more about endurance than speed, although speed is also asked. I require tips / techniques to be able to run longer / further, not so much faster. I would like to one day be able to run a full marathon.

Comment: Revise your running technique (if you have not done that already). It does not sound as a leg weakness problem.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a good runner. But I enjoyed a great amount of various pains and issues during running. The suggested plan how to avoid all the problems follows:

1. **Revise your running technique**. This step is the most crucial and you should not skip it. If you find an issue in your technique. Correct it. Test it for few months. If you do not know how to check your technique, hire a professional (choose carefully).
2. **Do mobility drills**. The book [Ready to Run: Unlocking Your Potential to Run Naturally](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1628600098) is far the best textbook (at least as I know). Test all new exercises/drills for few months at least
3. Additionally on top of that, you should add some strength training (as you suggest/request). Great place to start is http://www.strongfirst.com/training-the-endurance-athlete/

Note that all three steps are strongly related together. The mobility and strength is a must for safe running (as for everything else).

Comment: Thank you @matousc, I will try these tips. As soon as I can upvote, I will upvote this answer for you.